# Асинхронный сокет

Tags: c, linux, сокет

Возможно ли перевести сетевой Linux сокет в асинхронный режим работы?
Желательно пример на Си или C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то в таком духе.

```
signal(SIGIO, hsig);
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 
  fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_ASYNC);
fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());
```

Учтите (это я по аналогии с `O_NONBLOCK`), что уже dup-нутые дескрипторы даже в других процессах тоже станут асинхронными (впрочем, лучше проверьте это предупреждение).

**UPD**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define fatal(msg) ({fprintf(stderr,"FATAL %ld: %s [%m]\n",(long)getpid(),msg);\
      exit(-1);})

void hsig (int s)
{
  printf("catch %d (%s)\n", s, strsignal(s));
}

// returns 1 OK, 0 ERR
int
make_ipaddr (char *host, int port, struct sockaddr_in *a)
{
  struct hostent     *phe;

  a->sin_family = AF_INET;
  a->sin_port = htons(port);
  a->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;  

  if (host && host[0]) {
    if (phe = gethostbyname(host))
      memcpy (&a->sin_addr, phe->h_addr, phe->h_length);
    else 
      if ((a->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(host)) == INADDR_NONE) 
        return 0;
  }

  return 1;
}

// returns socket
int
make_connect (struct sockaddr_in *addr)
{
  int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0),
    alen = sizeof(*addr), on = 1;
  struct linger ling; 
  ling.l_onoff  = 1;
  ling.l_linger = 0;

  if (sock != -1 && 
      setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR, 
                 (char *)&on, sizeof (on)) != -1 &&
      setsockopt(sock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_LINGER,
                 (char *)&ling,sizeof(ling)) != -1 &&
      connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)addr,alen) == 0)
    return sock; // OK
  // ERR
  return sock == -1? -1: close(sock),-1;
}

int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in sadr;
  if (!make_ipaddr("localhost", atoi(av[1] ? av[1] : "1234"), &sadr))
    fatal("make addr");
  char buf[LINE_MAX];

  int fd = make_connect(&sadr);
  if (fd < 0)
    fatal("connect");

  signal(SIGIO, hsig);
  fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 
        fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_ASYNC);
  fcntl(fd, F_SETOWN, getpid());

  puts("Ready");
  getchar();

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Я соединялся этой программкой с `nc -l localhost -p 1234`

Comment: Для чего так много функций? Использую fcntl(sock, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK); и кажется этого достаточно.

Comment: @mikelsv, Вы круглое (`O_NONBLOCK`) с мягким (`O_ASYNC`) не путаете? Хотя, вполне возможно, что ТС имел в виду неблокируемый (`O_NONBLOCK`) сокет, а спросил об асинхронном (это тот,  где при появлении данных система шлет процессу сигнал).

Comment: Действительно, путаю. Раз асинхронность, значит неблокируемые стокеты.

Comment: @mikelsv, наверное практическй смысл использовать неблокируемые сокеты (кроме epoll с EPOLLET) это отлавливание ситуации, когда мы будем блокированы на **send()** из-за отсутствия места в буферах ОС. Но это легко разруливается флагом `MSG_DONTWAIT` в send().

Comment: Хмм, давайте посчитаем. Да, первым требуется избежать блокировки send(), дальше на всякий случай recv(). Также крайне нужно отсутствие блокировки в connect(), использую в прокси, спасает от подвисаний. А еще есть SSL_read(), которая как недавно оказалось могла бы подвисать, а при неблокирующих сокетах просто выдает ошибку SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ. Так что ситуаций предостаточно, чтобы в неблокирующих сокетах был смысл.

Comment: @mikelsv, прямо скажем, блокировка recv означает ошибку где-то в логике (ведь попадаете на него наверняка после select/poll/...), неблокируемый connect -- на мой взгляд экзотика, а вот с SSL это интересно (если не те же грабли, что и в обычном recv).

Comment: Предполагаю, что при посылке части SSL данных сработает select() и передаст управление SSL_read(), а дальше программа повиснет на нем, так как SSL будет ждать остальной части данных. Перестану лениться, проверю, как оно на самом деле.

Comment: Вопрос задан именно о работе сетевого сокета (сокета Беркли) в асинхронном режиме. Встречал в различных источниках, что сокеты в асинхронном режиме в ядре Linux не работают. Перевести в асинхр. режим можно только обычные строковые или бинарные файлы. Хотелось уточнить, можно ли написать обработчик сигнала SIGIO для сетевого асинхронного сокета.

Comment: @tomas, я его (асинхронный сокет)  никогда не использовал, но как-то работает. Попробовал программку (см. UPD ответа) с nc -l localhost -p 1234 -- SIGIO при отправке данных от nc она получает. Дальше экспериментируйте сами.